# libtorch conv2d kernel size

Tags: conv-neural-network, libtorch

Is there a way to set different kernel size for covn2d using libtorch (C++)?
For instance I want a kernel size (1,10)

```
torch::nn::Conv2d(torch::nn::Conv2dOptions(32, 32, (1,10)))
```

but Conv2dOptions only take 3 parameters.

Any suggestion would be much appreciated!

Comment: The kernel size is type ExpandingArray. https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/structtorch_1_1nn_1_1_conv_options.html#_CPPv4N5torch2nn11ConvOptions11ConvOptionsE7int64_t7int64_t14ExpandingArrayI1DE

Answer (score 0):

The kernel size hqs the type ExpandingArray which cqn be constructed from an initializer list, hence this should work :

```
torch::nn::Conv2d(torch::nn::Conv2dOptions(32, 32, {1,10}));
```